# Hosmer-Lemeshow test of goodness-of-fit Error Linear Model Y response NULL

Tags: r

Hosmer-Lemeshow test of goodness-of-fit. Received Error.

I have removed NA, with complete.cases(), then ran the lm() model: model.farm; then invoked the Hosmer-Lemeshow test of goodness-of-fit [hoslem.test()].

Still receive an error on the model.frame for variable lengths found for 'cutyhat'; checked stackoverload, indicating that the model had NA, so that is why I invoked another model with removed NA with complete.cases(). Stuck on this hoslem.test() issue..

```
df_farmpond <- df_farmpond[complete.cases(df_farmpond),]
hl_test <- hoslem.test(model.farm.lm$y, fitted(model.farm.lm), g = 5)

> hl_test

    Hosmer and Lemeshow goodness of fit (GOF) test

data:  model.farm.lm$y, fitted(model.farm.lm)
X-squared = 3.705, df = 3, p-value = 0.2951
```

Model details:

```
model.farm.lm$y [ notice below that for the attr(response) is 1
model.farm.lm$coefficients
model.farm.lm$residuals
model.farm.lm$terms
```

Outputs:

```
> model.farm.lm$y
NULL
> model.farm.lm$coefficients
  (Intercept)       TOTNITR  W_DEPTH_MEAN          TURB        DISOXY 
 0.9418943249  0.0379515587 -0.0063822052 -0.0066322266 -0.0001687033 
         COND          TEMP     POND_AREA 
-0.0010308852  0.0125638141 -0.1234772509 
> model.farm.lm$residuals
          1           2           3           4           5           6 
 0.13858538  0.38573515 -0.73602796 -0.04587555  0.04449845  0.22675387 
          7           8           9          10          11          12 
 0.10548684 -0.71244779 -0.84780380 -0.46894026  0.27773610 -0.35107919 
         13          14          15          16          17          18 
-0.54448867 -0.36493492  0.30847012  0.64836035  0.08619462  0.19139021 
         19          20          21          22          23          24 
 0.14290952  0.36942073 -0.78639655  0.24397498  0.08221528  0.30072828 
         25          26          27          28          29          30 
 0.35988554  0.33902600  0.14086306  0.09742289  0.03935141  0.27621187 
         31          32          33          34          35          36 
 0.09366211  0.32327669  0.15211771  0.11306520  0.07397839  0.39980076 
         37          38          39          40 
 0.12688801 -0.57702384  0.04345443 -0.69644542 
> model.farm.lm$terms
RICH ~ TOTNITR + W_DEPTH_MEAN + TURB + DISOXY + COND + TEMP + 
    POND_AREA
attr(,"variables")
list(RICH, TOTNITR, W_DEPTH_MEAN, TURB, DISOXY, COND, TEMP, POND_AREA)
attr(,"factors")
             TOTNITR W_DEPTH_MEAN TURB DISOXY COND TEMP POND_AREA
RICH               0            0    0      0    0    0         0
TOTNITR            1            0    0      0    0    0         0
W_DEPTH_MEAN       0            1    0      0    0    0         0
TURB               0            0    1      0    0    0         0
DISOXY             0            0    0      1    0    0         0
COND               0            0    0      0    1    0         0
TEMP               0            0    0      0    0    1         0
POND_AREA          0            0    0      0    0    0         1
attr(,"term.labels")
[1] "TOTNITR"      "W_DEPTH_MEAN" "TURB"         "DISOXY"       "COND"        
[6] "TEMP"         "POND_AREA"   
attr(,"order")
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
attr(,"intercept")
[1] 1
attr(,"response")
[1] 1
attr(,".Environment")
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
attr(,"predvars")
list(RICH, TOTNITR, W_DEPTH_MEAN, TURB, DISOXY, COND, TEMP, POND_AREA)
attr(,"dataClasses")
        RICH      TOTNITR W_DEPTH_MEAN         TURB       DISOXY         COND 
   "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric" 
        TEMP    POND_AREA 
   "numeric"    "numeric" 
>
```

Data glimpse:

```
glimpse(df_farmpond)
Observations: 40
Variables: 9
$ RICH         <int> 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, …
$ FISH         <int> 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, …
$ TOTNITR      <dbl> 0.56485714, 0.78157143, 0.84057143, 0.14528571, 0.1934…
$ W_DEPTH_MEAN <dbl> 26.56, 27.61, 13.95, 7.10, 7.54, 26.39, 16.66, 8.20, 9…
$ TURB         <dbl> 9.900000, 38.416667, 15.533333, 17.400000, 20.542857, …
$ DISOXY       <dbl> 9.639286, 11.457143, 9.871429, 13.085714, 10.292857, 1…
$ COND         <dbl> 91.87500, 173.83333, 262.50000, 333.65476, 67.46429, 1…
$ TEMP         <dbl> 22.30357, 22.83929, 22.75000, 23.42857, 22.71429, 22.2…
$ POND_AREA    <dbl> 0.41, 0.26, 0.48, 5.58, 0.19, 0.04, 0.12, 0.30, 0.06, …
```

Model:

```
formula_farm_AIC <- RICH ~ TOTNITR + W_DEPTH_MEAN + TURB + DISOXY + COND + TEMP + POND_AREA
model.farm.lm <- glm(formula = formula_farm_AIC, data = df_farmpond, family = binomial)
```

Execution to create the glm model:

```
> formula_farm_AIC <- RICH ~ TOTNITR + W_DEPTH_MEAN + TURB + DISOXY + COND + TEMP + POND_AREA
> model.farm.lm <- glm(formula = formula_farm_AIC, data = df_farmpond, family = binomial)
Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
>
```

summary(model.farm.lm):

```
> summary(model.farm.lm)

Call:
glm(formula = formula_farm_AIC, family = binomial, data = df_farmpond)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.82885  -0.08443   0.31020   0.53238   1.52997  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)   5.998810   5.925687   1.012   0.3114  
TOTNITR      -3.141090   1.776385  -1.768   0.0770 .
W_DEPTH_MEAN -0.039468   0.074696  -0.528   0.5972  
TURB         -0.025171   0.035452  -0.710   0.4777  
DISOXY       -0.155921   0.214229  -0.728   0.4667  
COND         -0.008091   0.003886  -2.082   0.0373 *
TEMP          0.053846   0.249877   0.215   0.8294  
POND_AREA    -0.733638   0.739312  -0.992   0.3210  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 50.446  on 39  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 30.048  on 32  degrees of freedom
AIC: 46.048

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 8
```

Comment: You are showing us how you used `complete.cases`, but you are not showing us where `model.farm` comes from. Can you please create a complete minimal example that recreates your issue?

Comment: Now have a successful run of Hosmer and Lemeshow goodness of fit (GOF) test

data:  model.farm.lm$y, fitted(model.farm.lm)
X-squared = 3.705, df = 3, p-value = 0.2951

Answer (score 0):

Solution on hoslam.test() run from glm model.

hl_test <- hoslem.test(model.farm.lm$y, fitted(model.farm.lm), g = 5)

Outcome:

```
> hl_test

    Hosmer and Lemeshow goodness of fit (GOF) test

data:  model.farm.lm$y, fitted(model.farm.lm)
X-squared = 3.705, df = 3, p-value = 0.2951
```